# Balloon Tip on any control like notify icon?

Tags: c#, winforms, balloon-tip

I have a win form application with custom tray Icon like this:

[image: Left BOTTOM Corner of Form]

I want to a notification with balloon tip to user like windows tray icon, 
with **close button** and show to user for ever until pressed close button):

[image: Exapmle]

Using tool tip in ballon mode can help me, But tool tip not have a **close button**.

Thanks.

Comment: Repeated question, I find this:
[Add close button (red x) to a .NET ToolTip]

  http://stackoverflow.com/q/245045/440030

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
TaskbarIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000,"Title","Message",ToolTipIcon.None);
```

this adds close button to baloon

Comment: In question i mentioned this is a custom tray icon,not a taskbar tray icon, see the images.

Comment: You can use custom controll like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2681/Balloon-Windows-for-NET